# Trying to make a login form

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, odbc

I am having some trouble.. I have an Index site where I type in my Username and Password to procceed to another page using a check. But I can't get the redirect to work! I am new to this and I apologize in advance if Im doing wrong or not posting correctly!

This is my check:

```
<?php

//- Initiate variables
$loggedin = false;

//- Try to login
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

//- Connect to database
$db = odbc_connect("WEBDATA", "", "") or die(odbc_errormsg());

//- Define $username and $password 
$username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username'])); 
$password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password'])); 

//- Get user from database  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WEBUSERS WHERE D01_Username = '$username' AND D02_Password = '$password'";
$rs  = odbc_exec($db, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());

//- Get user data 
if(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
  $username = odbc_result($rs,"D01_Username");
  $password = odbc_result($rs,"D02_Password");
  $language = odbc_result($rs,"D03_Language");
  $caltype  = odbc_result($rs,"D10_CAListType");
  $calist   = odbc_result($rs,"D11_CAList");
  $aaltype  = odbc_result($rs,"D12_AAListType");

  if (($_POST['username'] == $username) && ($_POST['password'] == $password)) {    
     $loggedin = true;  // Valid username and password

     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['language'] = $language;
     $_SESSION['caltype']  = $caltype;
     $_SESSION['calist']   = $calist;
     $_SESSION['aaltype']  = $aaltype;
     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $loggedin;
     $_SESSION['randkey']  = 'QgY' . rand(10,99) . 'HHe';
  }
}

//- Close database.
 odbc_close($db);

 //- Login or return
  if($loggedin == true)  header("location:hello.php");
  else        header("location:webrel_login.php");
 }
?>
```

And this is where I intent to go:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) header('location:webrel_login.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

It works like a charm if I dont have this code part:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) header('location:webrel_login.php'); ?>
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see `session_start()` in your code - that's required for sessions to work properly

Comment: You can't use 'header' after echoing or output something to user's screen. Check if you do this in you php file where you redirecting.It might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you seam to not have your session initialized. There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. you can initialize the session in each file like this:

check page

```
<?php

//start the session
session_start();

//- Initiate variables
$loggedin = false;

//- Try to login
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

//- Connect to database
$db = odbc_connect("WEBDATA", "", "") or die(odbc_errormsg());

//- Define $username and $password 
$username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username'])); 
$password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password'])); 

//- Get user from database  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WEBUSERS WHERE D01_Username = '$username' AND D02_Password = '$password'";
$rs  = odbc_exec($db, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());

.
.
.
```

and landing page

```
<?php 
//start the session
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) header('location:webrel_login.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

2. Initialize the sessions in a "config" file which you will have included in all major files (this is the way I recommend you to use)

config.php

```
<?php
   session_start();

   //initialize other important vars
   //like DB vars
   //or starting session vars
?>
```

check page

```
<?php

//include config.php
require_once('/path/to/config.php');

//- Initiate variables
$loggedin = false;

//- Try to login
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

//- Connect to database
$db = odbc_connect("WEBDATA", "", "") or die(odbc_errormsg());

//- Define $username and $password 
$username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username'])); 
$password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password'])); 

//- Get user from database  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WEBUSERS WHERE D01_Username = '$username' AND D02_Password = '$password'";
$rs  = odbc_exec($db, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());

.
.
.
```

and landing page

```
<?php 
//include config.php
require_once('/path/to/config.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) header('location:webrel_login.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ;) no problem! accept the answer so other users can benefit from it and the question can be closed :)